# Relationship among class field theory, modularity theorem, and the langlands program

Tags: nt.number-theory, langlands-conjectures

Here is some background: I have taken an introductory algebraic number theory course up to valuation-theoretic approach, learned a bit of local class field theory, representation theory, and modular forms.

Recently, I read an introductory exposition on Langlands program by Stephen Gelbart. Then if my understanding is correct, the Langlands program is to find a (conjectured) correspondence $\sigma \mapsto \pi_\sigma$ where $\sigma: G(E/\mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a $n$-dimensional representation of the Galois group $G(E/\mathbb{Q})$ with $E/\mathbb{Q}$ Galois, and $\pi_\sigma$ is an "automorphic representation of $GL_n$" satsifying

#### $L(s, \sigma) = L(s,\pi_\sigma)$

where the LHS $L$-function is due to Artin and the RHS $L$-function corresponds to the automorhpic form $\pi_\sigma$.

He then gives an application of the above to $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ with $\sigma: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^\times$ defined by $\sigma(id) =1, \sigma(cx~conj) = -1$, and an appropriate character $\chi : (\mathbb{Z}/4 \mathbb{Z})^\times \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^\times$. Here the $cx~conj$ is the complex conjugation.

**My first question is**: does $\chi$ play the role of the corresponding automorphic form $\pi_\sigma$ of $\sigma$ with $n=1$, so the class field theory is just a 1-dimensional class of Langlands program?

The math stackexchange article

[Why is Class Field Theory the same as Langlands for GL_1?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66500/why-is-class-field-theory-the-same-as-langlands-for-gl-1)

was beyond my understanding.

Also, I read a commentary of Edward Frankel on Gelbart's article saying that the Taniyama-Shimura conjecture is

“...a special case of the Langlands correspondence for the field of rational numbers: it relates two-dimensional Galois representations on the first etale cohomology of elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ to the automorphic representations of the group $GL_2$ over the $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q}$ encoded by certain modular forms on the upper half-plane.”

i.e. the $n=2$ case of the Langlands program.

**My second question is**: does the first $\acute{\text{e}}$tale cohomology of elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ corresponds to $\sigma$ and the modular forms give rise to the automorphic representation $\pi_\sigma$?

Any comments or inspirations are appreciated. Thank you in advance.

P.S. I have posted this questions in math stackexchange, but I wasn't getting any answer. I read a tip to migrate the question to math overflow. Please let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: The mse question is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022806/the-relationship-between-class-field-theory-modularity-theorem-and-the-langlan). To the OP, I would in general wait more than a day before pushing up to MO (disclaimer - this isn't my field, I can't tell whether this question is appropriate for MO or not, so I'm just saying this as a matter of general practice).

Comment: There is a subtlety, often glossed over in introductory expositions. There are several correspondences, all conjectural. There's a correspondence between $\pi$'s "of Artin type" and $\sigma$ as in your question (complex Galois reps). There's another one between "algebraic" $\pi$'s and motives (e.g. elliptic curves), via $p$-adic Galois representations, and a third between all $\pi$'s and complex representations of the global Langlands group (which doesn't yet exist). Strictly speaking the answer to your second question is no, because $\sigma$ coming from etale cohomology isn't a complex rep.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I will erase the mse question for now. I understand that I should have waited, but I'm in a situation where I might not be able to use the internet in a few days. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: As for class field theory, the answer is yes: Dirichlet characters give auto reps of GL_1, this is a good exercise (but you'll need to know the proper adelic definition of an auto rep so p-adics, adeles, relationship to class groups etc).

Comment: @znt Thank you for the clarification. I knew that there should be more to Frankel's comment.

Comment: In particular one might note that if $E$ is an elliptic curve over $Q$ and $\pi$ is the corresponding automorphic representation, then Langlands' most general conjecture would predict the existence of a 2-dimensional complex representation of a group that we can't define attached to $\pi$; the image (appropriately normalised) would I believe land in $U(2)$, and $Frob_\ell$ would be sent to a complex 2x2 matrix with char poly $X^2-a_\ell/\ell X+1$; Sato-Tate is that these Frobenii are equidistributed in the image. Nothing to do with the Tate module at all and still open (because no defn of gp).

Comment: @libofmath For dimension 1, try to understand the following statement. There is a continuous bijection between finite index Hecke characters $I_K \to \Bbb{C}^\times$ and continuous representations $G_K \to \Bbb{C}^\times$ where $I_K$ is the idele class group. The bijection essentially follows from existence and properties of the Global Artin map.