# Why arithmetic Langlands?

Tags: nt.number-theory, l-functions, langlands-conjectures

In trying to understand the import of Akshay Venkatesh' most recent work I found myself wondering anew about that old gnawing mystery: *why* Langlands? Why should arithmetic of polynomial equations over the rationals (and their generalizations) have anything to do with modular forms (and their generalizations), let alone have such a precise relationship as conjectured by arithmetic Langlands correspondence?

Even after decades of its formulation and spectacularly successful resolution in some cases - even more so for its geometric and $p$-adic analogues - my understanding of the literature is that the essential mystery remains in that beyond the equality of L-functions we don't have much of an inkling, at least in print, of a more direct relationship between the two sides, e.g., an action of (entities on) one side on the other, a direct map from one to the other, or both sides springing from a common source.

Of course, my reading of the literature may be wrong. It is certainly very incomplete. The proofs of special cases may well have provided insights into why these two sides seemingly so far apart should be so intimately related. If so, are they available publicly in a manner that I can access them? I'd also appreciate if you'd share your own here.

Finally, to bring it back to where I had begun: is the recent work of Venkatesh and co-workers (e.g., Kartik Prasanna and Akshay Venkatesh, *[Automorphic cohomology, motivic cohomology, and the adjoint L-function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.06370)*, see appendix A esp.) a step in the direction of showing a more direct relationship?

Comment: Most $L$-functions are not motivic. They are just there, and this is good so.

Comment: Regarding "The proofs of special cases may well have provided the practitioners with insights into why these two sides seemingly so far apart should be so intimately related," see this MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66500/why-is-class-field-theory-the-same-as-langlands-for-gl-1/66505#66505

Comment: "among the myriad (if not quite thirteen) ways of looking at a modular form...." A myriad is considerably greater than 13.

Comment: @Gerry "among the myriad ..." - too subtle an attempt at humor perhaps. I have removed the distraction.

Comment: @GerryMyerson probably objects to people's usage of "decimate" as well ;)